# Is there any callback function for change of Item values in GuideDropDownList in latest API?

Tags: javascript, aem

There is a **elementValueChanged** callback in **GuideBridge** API but none to check the change in Item values of **GuideDropDown** element.
Is there any existing callback in the latest API or any other work around for performing this task.

elementValueChanged does not work for **itemsChange**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no callback available for changes in the items of GuideDropDown. The GuideBridge API exposes only select functionality with a lot of operations happening internally.

If changing the items of the dropdown focuses the field, you can try to use the `elementFocusChanged` event and see if you can perform any operation that you wish to. In case it doesn't, then I am unsure.